# Why does PhpStorm report an "Argument type does not match" error?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, php-7, type-hinting

I am working on a **PHP 7** project with **PhpStorm 10.0.2**.

Whenever I declare a PHPDoc `@param` for an function parameter that has type hinting for a scalar type (`string`, `int`, ...) I get this warning:

> Argument type does not match

Here is some sample code that PhpStorm complains about:

```
class HostConfig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $hostname;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $domainname;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of hte HostConfig model.
     *
     * @param string $hostname   A host name (e.g. "dev", "int", "feature-xy")
     * @param string $domainname A domain name (e.g. "example.com")
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the given $hostname is empty
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the given $domainname is empty
     */
    public function __construct(string $hostname, string $domainname)
    {
        if (strlen(trim($hostname)) === 0) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The host name cannot be empty");
        }

        if (strlen(trim($domainname)) === 0) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The domain name cannot be empty");
        }

        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->domainname = $domainname;
    }
}
```

And a screenshot of PhpStorm displaying the questionable "Argument type does not match"-hint for in the PHPDoc for an constructor that has two strongly typed string parameters:

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm displaying an "Argument type does not match" hint for a string function parameter that has type hinting]

Does anybody know if I am doing something wrong or if this is just a bug in PhpStorm?

Comment: I use PHPStorm daily over the last couple of years and unfortunately it's riddled with irritating bugs like this between releases.

Comment: @Marty Why do you keep using it? Why have you not switched?

Comment: @BeetleJuice To what? Nothing else has the same PHPDoc support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of PHPStorm was released only 7 days after PHP 7 so its support for the new features of the language (including scalar type hinting) isn't great.  You're experiencing an IDE bug. Your issue is [probably this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28283) which is fixed with [PHPStorm 10.0.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/01/phpstorm-10-0-3/)